# c++: Where to delete an object and converting objects back to a member of a parent class

Tags: c++, oop, serial-port

I have a simple Message class and a simple SerialPort Class.  I also have a specific message subclass and a specific serial port subclass (CustomMessage & CustomSerialPort):

```
class Message
{
public: 
    uint8 getLength() const ( return m_length; }
    const uint8* getData() const { return m_contents; }
...
}

class SerialPort
{
public:
    bool OpenSerial(int32& errcode);  
    bool ReadFromSerial(int32& errcode, Message& msg);  
    bool WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, Message& msg, 
        uint32* const nBytesWritten);
...
}
```

Here are the custom classes.  Note that I overloaded the WriteToSerial() to take CustomMessage instead of just Message.

```
class CustomSerialPort : public SerialPort
{
public:
    bool WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, CustomMessage& msg, 
        uint32* const nBytesWritten);
...
}

class CustomMessage : public Message 
{
    // lots of stuff for messages to specific device
}
```

Also important, the implementation of CustomSerial::WriteToSerial and CustomMessage::toMessage()

```
bool CustomSerialPort::WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, CustomMessage& msg, 
    uint32* const nBytesWritten)
{
    SerialPort::WriteToSerial(errcode, msg.toMessage(), nBytesWritten);
}

Message& CustomMessage::toMessage() 
{
    Message* msg = new Message(m_contents, m_length);
    return *msg;
}
```

You can see that I call the WriteToSerial of the SerialPort class and send it a CustomMessage that has been converted to a Message.

**My question is this:  where should I delete the message that I created to pass to SerialPort::WriteToSerial?**

Or, should I do something more like this:

```
bool CustomSerialPort::WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, CustomMessage& msg, 
    uint32* const nBytesWritten)
{
    // don't use new
    Message m(msg);

    SerialPort::WriteToSerial(errcode, m, nBytesWritten);
    // deleted when goes out of scope
}
```

Then, with option 2, if my understanding is correct, I just need to make a Message constructor that takes a parameter of CustomMessage... wait... that seems weird.. taking a child class object parameter in a parent class constructor.  Do I need to rethink this?

Comment: Option 2 would be an example of the slicing problem so I wouldn't recommend using that.

Comment: @Csq I think I'm going to go with billz answer below, but what if I don't care about the information I'm losing to slicing (e.g. I'm storing everything I need in a buffer), including all the message specific stuff that is stored in member variables in CustomMessage, kinda like a serialize function.  Then would slicing it be so bad, if I plan to send it immediately after?

Comment: no, it would work correctly but such strange solutions cause bad maintainability to your code so generally you should avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `new Message` inside toMessage() and you don't need to delete it.

Change

```
Message& CustomMessage::toMessage() 
{
    Message* msg = new Message(m_contents, m_length);
    return *msg;
}

bool CustomSerialPort::WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, CustomMessage& msg, 
    uint32* const nBytesWritten);
```

to

```
Message CustomMessage::toMessage() 
{
    return Message(m_contents, m_length);
}

bool CustomSerialPort::WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, const CustomMessage& msg, 
                                                     ^^^ const
    uint32* const nBytesWritten)
```

When `toMessage()` is called in WriteToSerial, it will be bind till WriteToSerial() function finishes.

Also you need to add **const** qualifier to all functions take `Message` as input

```
class SerialPort
{
public:
    bool OpenSerial(int32& errcode);  
    bool ReadFromSerial(int32& errcode, const Message& msg);  
    bool WriteToSerial(int32& errcode, const Message& msg, 
        uint32* const nBytesWritten);
...
}
```

Comment: Do I really want: bool ReadFromSerial(int32& errcode, const Message& msg); when I need to add info to that message that is read from the serial?  Won't adding const prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, DON'T use `new`. Only time you should use new is:
 1. you can't know how many objects you need beforehand, and the possible range is so vastly different between "few" and "many" that it's not reasonable to have a fixed size array or similar. 
 2. When the object has to last longer than your current function, and it's not plausible to pass in the object from a lower down function. 
 3. The type of the object can't be known before the object is created (particularly relevant in polymorphism).

Not using `new` helps in that you don't have to remember to `delete` it later.

If you do use `new`, then it's best if it's inside a resource-holding object - smart pointer or something similar - that way, again, you don't have to remember to delete it.